# Matlab: Orbits of Planetary Bodies

Tags: matlab, orbital-mechanics

The below code is something that I am cooking up. I am plotting the orbits of the Sun, Mercury, Earth and the Moon. I have gotten this far into the project but the orbit of Mercury is terrifyingly wrong. This is seen by typing "SunEarthMoon(2,50)" at the command prompt and viewing the bottom left plot. The logic behind the project is utilizing Newton's Second Law toggled with the command "ode45" to find the positions of the bodies during a given time interval. I've been staring at this for far too long. Can anyone help to fix the orbit of Mercury?

```
function [] = SunEarthMoon(years,framerate)
%% Clean Up
close all
clc

%% Initializaion
x_earth = 147300000000; % [m]
x_mercury = 57.91e9; % [m]
v_earth = 30257; % [m/s]
v_mercury = 47362; % [m/s]
r_sat = 384748000; % earth surface [m]
r_earth = 6367000; % earth radius [m]
v_sat = 1023; % relative velocity from earth [m/s]
a = 5.145; % Angle to vertical (y) axis
b = 90; % Angle to horizontal (x) axis in xz plane

x_earth_o = [x_earth; 0; 0];
x_sun_o = [0; 0; 0];
x_mercury_o = [x_mercury; 0; 0];
x_sat_o = [x_earth+r_sat+r_earth; 0; 0];
v_earth_o = [0; v_earth; 0];
v_sun_o = [0; 0; 0];
v_mercury_o = [0; v_mercury; 0];
v_sat_o = v_sat*[cos(pi/180*b)*sin(pi/180*a); cos(pi/180*a); sin(pi/180*b)*sin(pi/180*a)] + v_earth_o;
interval = years*[0 31536000];

%% Error Control
h = [0.01 36000];
tol = 100000;
Options.AbsTol = tol;
Options.MaxStep = h(2);
Options.InitialStep = h(1);

%% Analysis
ao = [x_earth_o; v_earth_o; x_sun_o; v_sun_o; x_sat_o; v_sat_o; x_mercury_o; v_mercury_o];
[t, x] = ode45(@earthfinal,interval,ao,Options);
for i = 1:length(t)
    R1(i) = (x(i,13)-x(i,1));
    R2(i) = (x(i,14)-x(i,2));
    R3(i) = (x(i,15)-x(i,3));
    R(i) = sqrt(R1(i)^2+R2(i)^2+R3(i)^2);
end
T_index_earth = find([1; x(:,4)].*[x(:,4);1]<=0);
T_index_moon = find([1; R2(:)].*[R2(:); 1]<=0);
for i = 4:length(T_index_earth)
    T_earth_semi(i-3) = (t(T_index_earth(i)-1)-t(T_index_earth(i-2)-1))/24/60/60;
end
T_earth = mean(T_earth_semi);
for i = 4:length(T_index_moon)
    T_moon_semi(i-3) = (t(T_index_moon(i)-1)-t(T_index_moon(i-2)-1))/24/60/60;
end
T_moon = mean(T_moon_semi);
D_earth = 0;
for i = 2:(T_index_earth(4)-1)
    D_earth = D_earth + sqrt((x(i,1)-x(i-1,1))^2+(x(i,2)-x(i-1,2))^2+(x(i,3)-x(i-1,3))^2);
end
D_moon = 0;
for i = 2:(T_index_moon(4)-1)
    D_moon = D_moon + sqrt((R1(i)-R1(i-1))^2+(R2(i)-R2(i-1))^2+(R3(i)-R3(i-1))^2);
end

%% Plots
q = framerate;
scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
figure('position', [0.05*scrsz(3) 0.05*scrsz(4) 0.75*scrsz(3) 0.85*scrsz(4)])
set(gcf,'name','Sun, Earth, and Moon Orbits')
for i = 1:length(t)/q
    subplot(2,2,1)
    plot3(x(1:i*q,1),x(1:i*q,2),x(1:i*q,3),'g',x(1:i*q,7),x(1:i*q,8),x(1:i*q,9),'r',x(1:i*q,13),x(1:i*q,14),x(1:i*q,15),'b',x(1:i*q,19),x(1:i*q,20),x(1:i*q,21),'black')
    axis(1.1*[min(x(:,1)) max(x(:,1)) min(x(:,2)) max(x(:,2)) 2*min(x(:,15)) 2*max(x(:,15))])
    xlabel('Universal X Coordinate (m)')
    ylabel('Universal Y Coordinate (m)')
    zlabel('Universal Z Coordinate (m)')
    title('Relative Orbits')
    legend('Earth','Sun','Moon')
    hold on
    plot3(x(i*q,1),x(i*q,2),x(i*q,3),'g-o',x(i*q,7),x(i*q,8),x(i*q,9),'r-o',x(i*q,13),x(i*q,14),x(i*q,15),'b-o',x(i*q,19),x(i*q,20),x(i*q,21),'black-o')
    hold off

    subplot(2,2,2)
    plot3(R1(1:i*q),R2(1:i*q),R3(1:i*q),'b',zeros(1,i*q),zeros(1,i*q),zeros(1,i*q),'g')
    axis(1.5*[min(R1) max(R1) min(R2) max(R2) min(R3) max(R3)])
    xlabel('Universal X Coordinate (m)')
    ylabel('Universal Y Coordinate (m)')
    zlabel('Universal Z Coordinate (m)')
    title('Relative Moon Orbit About Earth')
    hold on
    plot3(R1(i*q),R2(i*q),R3(i*q),'b-o',0,0,0,'g-o')
    text(0,1.45*max(R2),1.40*max(R3),sprintf('Orbital Period, T = %3.5g days',T_moon))
    text(0,1.45*max(R2),1.15*max(R3),sprintf('Orbital Circumference, D = %3.5g gigameters',D_moon*1e-9))
    hold off

    subplot(2,2,3)
    plot(x(1:i*q,1),x(1:i*q,2),'g',x(1:i*q,7),x(1:i*q,8),'r', x(1:i*q,19),x(1:i*q,20),'black')
    axis(1.5*[min(x(:,1)) max(x(:,1)) min(x(:,2)) max(x(:,2))])
    xlabel('Universal X Coordinate (m)')
    ylabel('Universal Y Coordinate (m)')
    title('Relative Earth Orbit About Sun')
    hold on
    plot(x(i*q,1),x(i*q,2),'g-o',x(i*q,7),x(i*q,8),'r-o',x(i*q,19),x(i*q,20),'black-o')
    text(1.45*min(x(:,1)),1.40*max(x(:,2)),sprintf('Orbital Period, T = %3.5g days',T_earth))
    text(1.45*min(x(:,1)),1.25*max(x(:,2)),sprintf('Orbital Circumference, D = %3.5g gigameters',D_earth*1e-9))
    text(1.45*min(x(:,1)),1.40*min(x(:,2)),sprintf('Time, t = %3.3g days',round(t(q*i)/24/60/60)))
    hold off

    subplot(2,2,4)
    plot(t(1:i*q)/(60*60*24),R(1:i*q)/1000,'b')
    axis([t(1)/24/60/60 t(end)/24/60/60 0.999*min(R)/1000 1.001*max(R)/1000])
    xlabel('Time,t (days)')
    ylabel('Orbit Radius, R (km)')
    title('Moon-Earth Distance')
    hold on
    plot(t(i*q)/(60*60*24),R(i*q)/1000,'b-o')
    hold off

    drawnow
end
end

%% Differential Equation Function
function [udot]= earthfinal(t,u)
m_earth = 5.9742e24; % [kg]
m_mercury = 3.285e23; % [kg]
m_sun = 1.98892e30; % [kg]
m_sat = 11110; % [kg]
G = 6.67300e-11; %[(m)^3(kg)^-1(s)^-2];

d_earth_sun = sqrt((u( 7,1)-u(1,1))^2+(u( 8,1)-u(2,1))^2+(u( 9,1)-u(3,1))^2);
d_earth_sat = sqrt((u(13,1)-u(1,1))^2+(u(14,1)-u(2,1))^2+(u(15,1)-u(3,1))^2);
d_sun_sat =   sqrt((u(13,1)-u(7,1))^2+(u(14,1)-u(8,1))^2+(u(15,1)-u(9,1))^2);
d_mercury_sun = sqrt((u(7,1) -u(19,1))^2 + (u(8,1) - u(20,1))^2 + (u(9,1)-u(21,1))^2);
d_mercury_earth = sqrt((u(1,1) -u(19,1))^2 + (u(2,1) - u(20,1))^2 + (u(3,1)-u(21,1))^2);
d_mercury_sat = sqrt((u(13,1) -u(19,1))^2 + (u(14,1) - u(20,1))^2 + (u(15,1)-u(21,1))^2);

% Earth motion
udot( 1,1) = u(4,1);
udot( 2,1) = u(5,1);
udot( 3,1) = u(6,1);
udot( 4,1) = m_sun*G*(u(7,1)-u(1,1))/d_earth_sun^3 + m_sat*G*(u(13,1)-u(1,1))/d_earth_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(19,1)-u(1,1))/d_mercury_earth^3;
udot( 5,1) = m_sun*G*(u(8,1)-u(2,1))/d_earth_sun^3 + m_sat*G*(u(14,1)-u(2,1))/d_earth_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(20,1)-u(2,1))/d_mercury_earth^3;
udot( 6,1) = m_sun*G*(u(9,1)-u(3,1))/d_earth_sun^3 + m_sat*G*(u(15,1)-u(3,1))/d_earth_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(21,1)-u(3,1))/d_mercury_earth^3;
% Sun Motion
udot( 7,1) = u(10,1);
udot( 8,1) = u(11,1);
udot( 9,1) = u(12,1);
udot(10,1) = m_earth*G*(u(1,1)-u(7,1))/d_earth_sun^3 + m_sat*G*(u(13,1)-u(7,1))/d_sun_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(19,1)-u(7,1))/d_mercury_sun^3;
udot(11,1) = m_earth*G*(u(2,1)-u(8,1))/d_earth_sun^3 + m_sat*G*(u(14,1)-u(8,1))/d_sun_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(20,1)-u(8,1))/d_mercury_sun^3;
udot(12,1) = m_earth*G*(u(3,1)-u(9,1))/d_earth_sun^3 + m_sat*G*(u(15,1)-u(9,1))/d_sun_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(21,1)-u(9,1))/d_mercury_sun^3;
% Satellite Motion
udot(13,1) = u(16,1);
udot(14,1) = u(17,1);
udot(15,1) = u(18,1);
udot(16,1) = m_earth*G*(u(1,1)-u(13,1))/d_earth_sat^3 + m_sun*G*(u(7,1)-u(13,1))/d_sun_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(19,1)-u(13,1))/d_mercury_sat^3;
udot(17,1) = m_earth*G*(u(2,1)-u(14,1))/d_earth_sat^3 + m_sun*G*(u(8,1)-u(14,1))/d_sun_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(20,1)-u(14,1))/d_mercury_sat^3;
udot(18,1) = m_earth*G*(u(3,1)-u(15,1))/d_earth_sat^3 + m_sun*G*(u(9,1)-u(15,1))/d_sun_sat^3 + m_mercury*G*(u(21,1)-u(15,1))/d_mercury_sat^3;
% Mercury Motion
udot(19,1) = u(22,1);
udot(20,1) = u(23,1);
udot(21,1) = u(24,1);
udot(22,1) = m_sun*G*(u(7,1)-u(19,1))/d_mercury_sun^3 + m_earth*G*(u(1,1)-u(19,1))/d_mercury_earth^3 + m_sat*G*(u(13,1)-u(19,1))/d_mercury_sat^3;
udot(23,1) = m_sun*G*(u(8,1)-u(20,1))/d_mercury_sun^3 + m_earth*G*(u(2,1)-u(20,1))/d_mercury_earth^3 + m_sat*G*(u(14,1)-u(20,1))/d_mercury_sat^3;
udot(24,1) = m_sun*G*(u(9,1)-u(21,1))/d_mercury_sun^3 + m_earth*G*(u(3,1)-u(21,1))/d_mercury_earth^3 + m_sat*G*(u(15,1)-u(21,1))/d_mercury_sat^3;
end
```

Comment: I believe the orbital radius you have for Mercury is in km, as opposed to metres. It may work if you change `x_mercury` to `57.91e9`?

Comment: Huzahh! It is fixed. Thank you!